# How to visualize biometric performance (authentication) involving a multi-part dataset?

Tags: data-visualization

The problem pertains to gait authentication using the [CASIA-B](http://www.cbsr.ia.ac.cn/english/Gait%20Databases.asp) dataset and its specification is as follows.

- The dataset is composed of the gait of 124 subjects over three covariate conditions: A, B and C, each taken over 11 simultaneous angles.
- An authentication algorithm is applied to this dataset and is evaluated.
- The performance is measured in FRR, FAR$_1$ and FAR$_2$ where

  - FRR is the false rejection rate
  - FAR$_1$ is the false acceptance rate of intruders unknown to the system
  - FAR$_2$ is the false acceptance rate of intruders known to the system
- There is no EER (equal error rate)
- AER can be calculated as $AER=\frac{FRR}{2}+\frac{FAR_1 + FAR_2}{4}$

So we have the above measures (FRR, FAR$_1$, FAR$_2$) for each of the three covariates for each of the 11 angles.

How to visualize this performance?

I was thinking of a bar-chart with 11 groups each having 3 bars for the AER (average error rate) of covariates A, B, C. However the variance in the performance is very small (~1 to 4%) and some values are zero.

Also, since this is not a threshold-based verification, the ROC curve cannot be applied to this problem.

Any help would be appreciated.